# How can you create an ActionScript-based Flash file that doesn't operate with a fixed framerate?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm creating an ActionScript-based flash file that only needs the screen to be updated in response to something happening behind the scenes.  As such, I don't need it to run with a fixed frame-rate.  Instead I just want to tell it to lay dormant until I explicitly tell it the screen needs to update.

However, I don't see any way to do that.  Can that be done?  (i.e. set the framerate to zero and manually force an update based on some user-defined event?)

For example's sake, if you can provide an example that just kicks off the update based on a simple timer, that would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the frame rate, it doesn't have to be fixed, and the lowest frame rate you can set is 0.01:

```
stage.frameRate = 0.01;
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot. Flash was originally designed to be an animation sequence, so that's something built into player and not possible to modify. You can, however, make very long intervals between frames. Well, long as in one second long, not one day long :) I would also guess that things like timers and enterFrame events wouldn't work for you if it was possible to prevent all frame updates.